# Run JS after radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have two radio buttons and that needs to fire a event according to what radio button is selected. Problem is that it fires immediately and doesn't let the user select an option. How I can get the user's input first and then run the JavaScript.

Here is the code:

```js
if (document.getElementById("radio_myself").checked == true) {
  alert(document.getElementById("radio_myself").value);
} else {
  alert(document.getElementById("radio_selse").value);
}
```

```html
<span><input id="radio_myself" name="radMyself" type="radio" value="Myself"/>Myself</span>
<span><input id="radio_selse" name="radSelse" type="radio" value="Someone"/>Someone Else</span>
```

Comment: You need an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: That script runs right away, but you want it to run it as `onchange` handler. Also `== true` is redundant and can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make them select one first by using a function on change. By giving them the same name only one at a time can be selected, this will let you return the correct value.
From Chris's comment  Also `== true` is redundant and can be removed, because checked is a boolean.

```js
function check() {
  if (document.getElementById("radio_myself").checked) {
    alert(document.getElementById("radio_myself").value);
  } else {
    alert(document.getElementById("radio_selse").value);
  }
}

addEventListener("change", ({target}) => { if(target.matches("input[type='radio']")){ check(); } })
```

```html
<span><input id="radio_myself" name="radSelse" type="radio" value="Myself"/>Myself</span>
<span><input id="radio_selse" name="radSelse" type="radio" value="Someone"/>Someone Else</span>
```